# Is "Ad astra, per sanguinem" the correct translation of "To the stars, through blood."

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary, translation-check

I am wanting to get this phrase as a tattoo. I want to make sure this is the best way to translate this to match the original meaning in English.

Also, I am wondering about this alternative phrase "Ad astra, meo sanguine." Supposedly meaning, "To the stars, with my blood"

Comment: What's the intended meaning here?

Answer (score 6):

If you are intending to parallel the Latin phrase *Ad astra per aspera*, then *ad astra per sanguinem* is precisely right.

Change that to *per sanginem meum* if you mean through my blood.

Using *sanguine meo* as a bare ablative means "by means of my blood". It might also mean "when the blood is mine", depending on context.

*Cum sanguine meo* means "with my blood".

Comment: Bare infinitive or ablative?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Doh! Many thanks.